# Access List items names as string

Tags: python, list

I need to access the items in list as strings , The items have the names and values like dataframe or integer values.How can I access the names of the items not the values in the list

```
values = [surcharges , data , dataframe , num]
```

it returns a value instead of name , I only need the name

```
for val in values:
    print(str(val))
```

or

```
print(str(val))
```

Comment: can you provide more details on what is your expected output and what you are getting?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a dictionary instead. You can  access the values as a list and refer to each value by a string name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this reliably. Consider this first:

```
foo = []
bar = 0
banana = {}

lst = [foo, bar, banana]

def func(lst):
    lst.append(zz := 100)
    for _id in map(id, lst):
        for k, v in globals().items():
            if id(v) == _id:
                print('Global', k)
                break
        else:
            for k, v in locals().items():
                if id(v) == _id:
                    print('Local', k)
                    break

func(lst)
```

The output will be:

```
Global foo
Global bar
Global banana
Local zz
```

Now, you may look at that and think "That works". Well, it does for this contrived example. Now let's make a small change:

```
foo = []
bar = 0
banana = {}
oops = bar

lst = [foo, bar, banana, oops]

def func(lst):
    lst.append(zz := 100)
    for _id in map(id, lst):
        for k, v in globals().items():
            if id(v) == _id:
                print('Global', k)
                break
        else:
            for k, v in locals().items():
                if id(v) == _id:
                    print('Local', k)
                    break

func(lst)
```

**Output:**

```
Global foo
Global bar
Global banana
Global bar
Local zz
```

So why did we see *bar* twice?

When we assign *bar* to *oops* we just get a new variable with a reference to the original object's ID. When we enumerate the globals() (in this case) we happen to observe the ID of *bar* before we see *oops*.

Therefore, if you enumerate a list and try to get the original variable names you may get ambiguous results.

In summary therefore, there's no reliable way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to achieve this, you would need to access the variable's `__name__` attribute. Unfortunately, while functions, classes and modules all define this attribute, variables do not.